# PHP MYSQL Display table column based on variable

Tags: php, mysql

Using the following variables

I have the Following table named everyones_friends;
id, john, jack, bill, dave
1, jack, john, dave, bill
2, bill, dave, john, jack
3 dave, bill, jack, john

doing the following query;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM everyones_friends";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata));
$display_column['$variable'];
```

My question is how do I display the "bill" column using a previously user selected variable since I know the $display_column['$variable']; won't work. Based on their choice one of the columns above goes into a dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/20019484/mysql-how-to-use-a-variable-as-column-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this line to be :

```
$display_column[$variable];
```

single quota in php doesn't parse php variables.